# Detect which apps are in desktop in Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

How can I detect which applications belong to the current desktop in OSX?

I have tried looking at NSWorkspace, which does list all the applications, but haven't found anything related to the Desktop in the application properties.

Comment: I think you're going to have to re-phrase this, as it doesn't make much sense to me as written. Applications don't belong to a Desktop (which isn't really an OS X term, anyway). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I'm on OSX right now, and Safari is in Desktop1, while VLC player is in Desktop2. I want to programatically know where each app (or main window) is. Does that make sense?

By Desktop I mean what other desktop managers call workspaces.

Comment: I think the `kCGWindowWorkspace` key may provide what you're looking for.